# Why does clusterEvalQ() return a list of attached packages when used with library()?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am new to the `parallel` package in Windows (having previously done most of my parallel stuff in Unix-like environments where the process just forked). I am trying to set up a cluster to do a simple set of parallel queries across a few different databases.

I seem to have the queries running fine at this point. However, when using `clusterEvalQ` to load RODBC into each of the environments, I am getting back a list of all packages loaded in that environment. I don't seem to get any analogous behavior with other commands in `clusterEvalQ`, so I was wondering if this is an intentional feature because I am specifically loading a package.

Why is `clusterEvalQ` only returning an output when I run the expression `library(RODBC)`?

A minimal working example / output is shown below.

```
> library(parallel)
> parallel.cluster <- makeCluster(spec = 5)
> clusterEvalQ(cl = parallel.cluster,expr = library(RODBC))
[[1]]
[1] "RODBC"     "methods"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"     

[[2]]
[1] "RODBC"     "methods"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"     

[[3]]
[1] "RODBC"     "methods"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"     

[[4]]
[1] "RODBC"     "methods"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"     

[[5]]
[1] "RODBC"     "methods"   "stats"     "graphics"  "grDevices" "utils"     "datasets"  "base"
```

Comment: To whomever voted to close without leaving a comment...could you clarify how I can be more clear in this question? I want to know "Why is clusterEvalQ only returning an output when I run the expression library(RODBC)?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clusterEvalQ` always returns the result of evaluating the expression on each of the cluster workers. The expression `library(RODBC)` returns a character vector of all the attached packages, but it does so invisibly. When executed via `clusterEvalQ`, it isn't invisible, so it's more obvious.

Comment: To add to this answer, it seems like the only other option for `library` is to use `logical.return = TRUE` to get a list of logicals (TRUE or FALSE) instead of a list of packages. That's a good way to reduce the printed text if you have a lot of packages loaded.